# Oracle LPad equivalent in entity framework core

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, entity-framework-core

I am trying to write a query in entity framework core where I am able to LPad the entity. I build up a PredicateBuilder by going through a loop and compare a string to the entity I'm trying to compare against

For example:

Model (Distributors):

```
public int Id {get;set;}
public decimal DistNo {get;set;}
```

For each loop in class

```
var searchPredicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Distributor>();

foreach (var code in codes)
{
   searchPredicate.Or(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.DistNo.ToString(), $"{code}%"));
}
```

I have tried this:

```
searchPredicate.Or(x => EF.Functions.Like(System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.Left("0" + x.DistNo.ToString(), 10), $"{code}%"))
```

But had no luck

What I'd like to happen is, when comparing "code" to "x.DistNo" is for the "x.DistNo" to be 0 padded on the left until its reached 10 characters. E.g. if x.DistNo in the db was 202930005 I'd want the query to see it as 0202930005 instead.

The oracle query I'm trying to replicate is:
select * from distributors
where lpad(dist_no, 10, '0') like '2%'

Comment: There are conflicting tags. EF 6 is not EF Core 6.

Comment: In c# you can use CONTAINS, STARTSWITH, and ENDSWITH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual path when seeking for a db function in EF Core is first standard CLR type property/method, then `EF.Functions` extension method (do not use anything from `System.Data.Entity` namespace, these are for "classic" Entity Framework (a.k.a. EF6) which is completely different from EF Core, and is not used/recognized by EF Core at all).

In this case, `string.PadLeft` CLR method looks appropriate, but the experiment shows that it is not supported by the EF Core database providers (most probably because MSFT owned SqlServer has no such function, and many design decisions of MSFT owned EF Core are still based on that database). Also there is no `EF.Functions` extension method, so looks like there is no solution.

But actually there is a solution thanks to the EF Core [User-defined function mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping) capability, which allows you to relatively easy add support for the desired translation.

For Oracle `LPAD`, you'll need a custom static class holding the method definition like this

```cs
public static class OracleDbFunctions
{
    [DbFunction(IsBuiltIn = true)]
    public static string LPad(this string text, int totalWidth, string padding)
        => throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

then registering it inside you context `OnModelCreating` override:

```cs
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(() => OracleDbFunctions.LPad(default, default, default));
```

Then you can use it in your query as any other:

```cs
x => EF.Functions.Like(OracleDbFunctions.LPad(x.DistNo.ToString(), "0"), $"{code}%")
```

It's not a perfect and general solution, since it is not database agnostic, but more like a workaround for unsupported specific database function.

Comment: Do you know how you would go about unit testing the new function? In my code I have added it to my model builder as: modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(() => OracleDbFunctions.LPad(default, default, default)); as you suggested and it works perfectly fine. However, now when I try to unit test the function on any of my api calls I get the error "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object" even though I have mocked all data correctly. Do you know how I would go about getting my mockDbContext to talk to the new function?

Comment: @Taran I'm afraid there is no solution for that, since even "canned" db functions (extension methods of `EF.Functions`) do not support testing - throw the same exception as the definition of `LPad`. Because when using `InMemory` provider, these are actually executed, so you are just hitting `throw new InvalidOperationException();` code. Instead of throwing exception, you could actually provide C# implementation (for instance, using `PadLeft`), but again, you cannot test `EF.Functions.Like` and similar, so it is generally useless.

Comment: thank you for your detailed responses Ivan they are much appreciated. Annoying that EF.Function don't support testing!